# Java EE + Wildfly: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, jboss

I'm trying to setup a maven project to work with Wildfly and and MySql and I'm getting this error, I'm pretty sure it's a configuration problem. I'm using Wildfly so I don't have any hibernate configuration files (which is related to all solutions I've found). This is what I'm getting. I just started learning how to deal with RIA's so any thoughts will be very much appreciated.

Question is mostly error log and code so thanks for the patience of anyone willing to help.

My console errors:

```
17:53:34,909 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."RPGo.war#RPGo": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."RPGo.war#RPGo": org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:125)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:640)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:875)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:167)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
    ... 19 more

17:53:34,909 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "RPGo.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"RPGo.war#RPGo\"" => "org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set"}}
17:53:34,940 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "RPGo.war" (runtime-name : "RPGo.war")
17:53:34,940 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."RPGo.war#RPGo": org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

My persistance.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
        <persistence-unit name="RPGo">
            <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
            <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/RPGo</jta-data-source>
            <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
            <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

standalone.xml, urn:jboss:domain:datasources subsystem

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/RPGo" pool-name="RPGoPool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rpgo</connection-url>
            <driver>mysql</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>master</user-name>
                <password>master</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
            <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

pom.xml dependencies:

```
<!-- JSF -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.13</version>
</dependency>

<!-- JSF -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.13</version>
</dependency>

<!-- PrimeFaces -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- CDI -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Métodos uteis para manipulação de String, métodos e etc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- PROVIDER JPA(HIBERNATE) -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- DEPENDENCIA MYSQL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.44</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Manipulação de XML -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>br.ufes.inf.nemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbutler-wp</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a bit of dependency pollution.

Modify your dependencies as follows and I believe that you will get up and running:

```
<!-- WildFly implements everything in this jar -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- PrimeFaces -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Métodos uteis para manipulação de String, métodos e etc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Manipulação de XML -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>br.ufes.inf.nemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbutler-wp</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Went to see my professor to talk about this issue, he gave me the exact same answer, I was double importing several dependencies, thanks a lot @Steve C, let this be a reference for future searchs.

Answer (score 2):

Add `<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>` into persistence.xml.

Also you should migrate from `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` which is deprecated in Hibernate 4.3 to `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`

Comment: `hibernate.dialect` is redundant in a correctly configured JPA 2.x application